# Remove the default interface CakePHP links in default Cake apps?

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I get rid of the default **"`CakePHP: the rapid development php framework`"** link that shows up on the top left on every page of Cake app's with default configurations? It's not part of the view, and the only way I can think of is to `display:none` the div in the CSS.

I'm thinking there has to be some setting in the app's configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modify `app/views/layouts/default.ctp`

If no view exists in that location, check `cake/libs/views/layout/default.ctp`

Answer (score 3):

You are using the default layout, which you can override by creating your own layout file in  `app/views/layouts/default.ctp`. See the [layout section](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1080/Layouts) in the cookbook for more information about layouts.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @dhofstet you can make simple copy from cake/libs/views/layout/default.ctp and place it in your app/views/layouts/default.ctp and modify.